# How do I access the datacontext of a silverlight control in the codebehind

Tags: silverlight

I've a silverlight control I am instantiating like so:

```
<MyControls:SomeControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

In the codebehind of this file, how can I get access to this datacontext? this.DataContext is equal to null.

Edit (more info):

I am building an extension for an existing silverlight application. My point where I integrate with the app looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AnImportantIdentifierUsedByTheHostApp">
    <MyControls:SomeControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Inside my control, I am able to bind against properties like so:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=UriWithSlug}">
```

And this all works fine. However for certain functionality (specifically, I need to use a WebBrowser control and the NavigateToString() method), I need to access properties from the DataContext.

Basically in the codebehind, I need to do something to the effect of:

```
myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(DataContext.MyHTMLStringProperty);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of course is super straight forward and something I'm sure everyone probably assumed I was doing...

The DataContext is not available until the control's `Loaded` event has fired.

```
public MyUserControl() {
    var dc = this.DataContext // DataContext is null here in the ctor.

    this.Loaded += (s, e) => {
        var sc2 = this.DataContext // Loaded event fires, DataContext exists!
    };
}
```

Again, I'm sure this is probably obvious to a lot of SL devs but it completely tripped me up.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  Do not feel alone, I made the same mistake.  Now, it does seem obvious that that DataContext would be null in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `DataContext={Binding}` since that is tantamount to `DataContext = DataContext`.

However what you are missing is type information.  Bindings use reflection to resolve property paths, however in code-behind you will need to know the type of the object returned by `DataContext`.

If you can be sure of that then it would simply be:-

```
myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(((MyType)DataContext).MyHTMLString);
```

If you can't be sure of the type and/or you can't persuade whoever controls the host of your controls to ensure at least a specific Interface with known members is implemented, then you might need to resort to reflection yourself.

**Use the binding system to do the reflection for you**

An alternative if you can't know the type only the name of the property:-

```
public string HTMLString
{
   get { return (string)GetValue(HTMLStringProperty); }
   set { SetValue(HTMLStringProperty, value); }
}
public static DependencyProperty HTMLStringPropery =
   DependencyProperty.Register(
      "HTMLString",
      typeof(string),
      typeof(SomeControl),
      null);
```

Now if you are sure you know the name of the property you want to bind you can set up the binding in code in your controls constructor:-

```
SetBinding(HTMLStringProperty, new Binding("MyHTMLString"));
```

With this in place your code would look like:-

```
myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(HTMLString);
```

Alternatively you would make binding this new property of your control the responsibility of the Xaml:-

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AnImportantIdentifierUsedByTheHostApp">                  
    <MyControls:SomeControl HTMLString="{Binding MyHTMLString}" />                  
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: OK, I've removed the DataContext={Binding} on the XAML that loads the control, and I DO know the type of the DataContext, however my issue still remains, in the code behind, DataContext is == null. myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(((MyType)DataContext).MyHTMLString); throws an exception because DataContext is null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, makes a little more sense now. Changing answer accordingly...

Basically you should never need DataContext={Binding}. The DataContext of an item is set (per item) by the parent control. In most list-type controls that is generated from the entries in the ItemsSource.

1. Can you remove the DataContext={Binding} and check that it still works?
2. If the actual child control has no explicit DataContext value itself, then to get the DataContext of a parent control you may have to navigate up the visual tree (until you find a non-null DataContext).

*Can you provide more of the code/xaml we we can see the above in context?*

Comment: Actually the `DataContext` property should return the current "non-null DataContext", it will search up the visual tree for you.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Quite right, but so little sleep last night I did not want to say that for sure :)

Comment: @HiTech Magic, that is pretty much all of the code, anything further up the tree is contained in the host app which I don't have access to. I have removed the DataContext={Binding} and my bindings still work, however DataContext is still null in the code behind.

Comment: @DaRKoN_: What container type is the DataTemplate within?

Comment: @HiTech Magic, a ResourceDictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
var mytype = this.DataContext as MyType;
```

As a precaution, I'll check for null afterwards:

```
if (mytype!=null)
{
    // do something here
    myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(mytype.MyHTMLStringProperty);
}
```

Comment: this.DataContext is always null! That's my problem!